# Need help in understanding the crash dump from logcat

Tags: debugging, android-ndk, android-logcat, crash-dumps, backtrace

I got this Crash dump from my logcat: [Crash dump from my logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCPgP.jpg)
(I erased in this image just the project name)

I wanted to know what thoes number's (+56 and +41 circled in red) means. Is it offset? And if so, offset from where?

Comment: Don't post error messages or code as images or links; add them as text directly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is offset in decimal from beginning of the function, so if you will use objdump on .so you need to find beginning of setCamParams and add decimal 41 to get point where it crashed (if you have source use intermix option to get mixed C/C++ and asm).